# How unload views in ios6?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, ios6

How unload views in ios6?

What is the best way to release views in ios6

```
previously used - (void) viewDidUnload
```

but now I'm confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove them from their superview:

```
 [view removeFromSuperview];
```

`viewDidUnload` is a method that is called as an effect of unloading a view; it will not make a view unload.

Ooops, now I realize you may mean a different thing... perhaps your question referred to the fact that `viewDidUnload` is not called anymore under iOS6 and you wonder how you recover memory when a memory warning is received.

In this case, I think the only option available is doing in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` what you used to do in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: i am used self.view = nil what is the difference?

Comment: `self.view = nil` will not necessarily unload your view; that has to do with memory management. If you have a view controller and add its view to another view (e.g., `UIWindow`, the very root view), then you have two pointers to it: `self.view` (property of your view controller), and its superview as well. So, the view will be unloaded only when both pointers do not refer the view anymore. For me, "unloading" has to do with removing from the superview; "releasing" with setting the pointer to nil.